# НастоящЕЕ/знанИЕ

Tags: орфография

Почему пишем мы *будущее, настоящее*, но *знание, доверие, условие, лезвие, здание* и т. д.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Настоящее знание.***

1. ***Будущ/ее, настоящ/ее*** (какое?) — окончание ***ОЕ/ЕЕ*** прилагательных **в форме** среднего рода, выбор Е после шипящих.
2. ***Знание, доверие, условие*** — суффикс существительных ***И(J)*** и  окончание ***Е***, выбор О/Е в начальной форме для существительных **среднего рода.**

Пример словосочетания: ***настоящ/ее знани/е.**  Согласование в роде, числе и падеже.

Comment: Почему *настоящее значенЕе*?

Comment: Вы хотите написать значенЕе?  Но это же неверно, у существительных нет такого суффикса (Е).

Comment: Вы это написали в конце!

Comment: Извините,  если что...